# Where is the folder after an app installed by sudo apt-get install (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, qt5

I have a problem with Ubuntu. I don't know where is folder located after I install an app with terminal.

Actually, I want to know where is `libqt5-mysql` located. I installed it but I couldn't find it anywhere. :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the contents of an installed package with the dpkg command:

```
dpkg -L libqt5-mysql
```

[dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/dpkg.1.html)